# To handle IOError, which method should I use?

Tags: haskell

I came across a function that, according to its documentation, can throw `IOError`. I want to handle this.

It looks like there are multiple ways of doing it. `Control.Exception` is one. `System.IO.Error` is another.

- Are there other ways?
- Which way do you recommend I use and why? Or what are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Here are some advice: http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#error-handling

Comment: I believe `System.IO.Error` is actually making use of `catch` from `Control.Exception` [under the hood](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/System.IO.Error.html#catchIOError)

Comment: @Alec. Yes, [`catchIOError = catch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/System.IO.Error.html#catchIOError)

Comment: @Cirdec I realize. Check the link in my comment, it is the same as yours. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type IOError = IOException
```

so both finish in Control.Exception.Base, ie `catch`. System.IO.Error is just a specialization package, to help you deal with those exceptions that are IO.